# Reusing Variable stored value in switch/case

Tags: java

I'm using Java to code a simple game. I am using a switch and would like to reuse the value obtained after the calculation is complete and the menu is displayed again for the user to choose, provided that the user chooses the same option again. That is the store the previous value and use that instead of the initial value to make calculations. The game ends when the "phystrength" variable equals 0.

This is a part of the code I have written:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw3{

```
public static void main(String []args) {
        class physician {

        int phystrength;
        int restoring;
        String available; 

    }       


    physician med = new physician ();

    med.phystrength=100;
    med.restoring=30;
    med.available="busy";

    class surgeon {

        int phystrength;
        int restoring;
        String available; 

    }       


    surgeon med1 = new surgeon ();

    med1.phystrength=100;
    med1.restoring=25;
    med1.available="busy";


    class nurses {

        int phystrength;
        int restoring;
        String available; 


    }       


    nurses med2 = new nurses ();

    med2.phystrength=90;
    med2.restoring=20;
    med2.available="busy";


    class anesthesia {

        int phystrength;
        int restoring;
        String  available; 


    }       


    anesthesia med3 = new anesthesia ();

    med3.phystrength=100;
    med3.restoring=30;
    med3.available="busy";


    //Declaring variables 
    int strength, strength1,strength2=0 ; 
    int numsurgeons=3;
    int numphysician= 3;
    int numnurses=10;
    int numanesthesia=2;
    int remsurgeons,remphysician,remnurses,remanesthesia=0;


Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); //Creating a Scanner object to read use input 

System.out.println("Welcome to National Cheng Kung University (NCKU) Hospital");

System.out.println();

System.out.println("Here is the list of current available medical staff at NCKU hospital");

System.out.println();

System.out.println("\nAvaialable personnel are (including their physical strength):"
                    +"\n\t 3 Surgeons -> " + med1.phystrength
                    + "\n\t 3 Physicians -> " + med.phystrength 
                    +"\n\t 10 Nurses -> " + med2.phystrength
                    + "\n\t 2 anesthesiologists -> " + med3.phystrength);

System.out.println("Please enter the NUMBER of the type of medical treatment you are in need of");

String selec;

while (true) { //Allows user to continue to choose from the menu 

    System.out.println ("\nPlease choose from the menu below:" 

                    + "\n\t Medical Treatment-0"
                    + "\n\t Dressing Wrap-1"
                    + "\n\t Surgery-2"
                    + "\n\t Chemotherapy-3"
                    + "\n\t Emergency-Surgery-4"
                    + "\n\t First Aid-5"
                    + "\n\t End Program-6");

selec = scan.next();

switch (selec)
{
case "0":

    System.out.println("You have chosen Medical Treatment (General)");
strength = med.phystrength-20;
strength1=med2.phystrength-10;
remphysician=numphysician-1;
remnurses=numnurses-1;

if (strength <100){
    System.out.println("Physician is: " + med.available);
}

System.out.println("Physician's current Physical strength is:" + strength);

System.out.println("Nurse's current physical strength is:"+ strength1);

System.out.println("Number of remaining Physicians is " + remphysician +" and number of remaining nurses is " + remnurses);
    break;
```

Comment: your code is broken, please include relevant components of the code.

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete. `phystrength` is a member of med, med1, med2 and med3.

Comment: You should name your variables with more intention. You can have `physician` and `nurse` be your variables. Then, you can declare a `getStrength()` method to get their respective current values.

Comment: Your request isn't clear, please provide some example or clarify yourself better

Comment: I apologize for I am new to this site and am a beginner programmer, hence am quite skeptic what all to include. Don't have much time coding. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So basically after the user chooses option "0" for example, the method is executed and the option is then displayed again. If the user chooses option "0" again, what I wanted the program to do is that instead of using the initial phystrength=100 value, to use the previously calculated phystrength after the method has executed once. That is, in the second calculation use phystrength=90.  hope this is clearer!

Comment: You need to set the value of the `med` variable. For instance, instead of `strength = med.phystrength - 20;`, you need to do something like `med.phystrength = med.phystrength - 20;`

Comment: Thanks!! Now, is there a way I can use the new value of med.phystrength as my initial value if the user inputs that same option again?  Kind of like looping, until perhaps equals zero whereby the game ends. Must I store the value using a new variable?

Comment: Got it!!!! Setting the value like you say works!! Could I just use an if function like this : if (med.phystrength==0){ System.out.println("Game over");  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is bad,

```
 class physician {
    int phystrength;
    int restoring;
    String available; 
}   

class surgeon {
    int phystrength;
    int restoring;
    String available; 
}
```

These are the exact same object, so you don't make new classes, you make `new` instances of one class.

So, only one of these.

```
class Medic {
    public int phystrength, restoring;
    boolean isAvailable; // true/false makes more sense than "busy" / "available"

    public Medic (int strength, int restoring, boolean available) {
        this.phystrength = strength;
        this.restoring = restoring;
        this.isAvailable = available;
    }
}
```

And many of these.

```
Medic physician = new Medic(100, 30, false);
Medic surgeon = new Medic(100, 25, false);
// ... etc.
```

---

Now, as far as your switch statement, try to scan for integers instead because that is what you are prompting for.

```
selec = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine(); // clear the newline

switch (selec) {
case 0:  // Case on integers, instead
    System.out.println("You have chosen Medical Treatment (General)");
```

And if you want to modify the state of your "staff", you actually need to change their status's directly, not store separate variables.

```
physician.phystrength -= 20;
nurse.phystrength -= 10; // "x -= y" --> "x = x - y"
remphysician=numphysician-1;
remnurses=numnurses-1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is more clear now. Any tips or resources that you would suggest to me as a starter programmer to improve on my programming skills?

Comment: Can't get much better than trial and error over reading the official tutorial. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ Of course, not everyone is capable of learning that way, though. Videos, or a proper teaching environment may be better.

Comment: thank you!! i will try the website. and thanks for your help again!

Comment: Hello. I am a bit confused on how to use the available boolean variable. What I want to do is when the user chooses say option "0" the program will display the physician is "busy". At the beginning the program will display the physician is "available". Thanks!

Comment: You can switch back to a String if you really want. But it's a really simple if statement... `if (nurse.isAvailable) System.out.println("available"); else System.out.println("busy")`